# Getting Wrong Number Of Char Variable

Tags: c++, char, signed

in below code when i run it i get `y=-124` and `z=4294967172` 
can you explain me?? (tested that if `x<128` there isnt any problem)

```
char x=132;
signed y=x;
unsigned z=x;
cout<<y<<endl;
cout<<z<<endl;
```

Comment: @iammilind:  That is completely wrong.  Even if there are unnamed padding bytes following `x`, they cannot in any way affect the semantics of the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char` is 8-bits, so when you write `char x = 132`, you actually do this:

```
x = 1000 0100
```

`signed int` and `unsigned int` both are 32-bits, and whenever you assign the value of a 'smaller' variable into a 'larger' one, the system uses **sign extension**, i.e. copies the sign bit to every bit to the left. So the value becomes:

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1000 0100
```

If you interpret it as a signed value, it's -124, and as an unsigned value it's 4294967172.

Moreover, if you define the `char` as `unsigned` in the first line, you would always get 132, as sign extension is not done for unsigned values.

Comment: wow thanks,very interesting thing i got here.also thanks to James McNellis to complete the answer and showed me the way to solve this

Answer (score 2):

`char`s are only 8-bit, which means they can only hold 256 values including 0. You're using a signed char, which means half the values are reserved for negative numbers, making the maximum positive value 127.

Comment: thanks,but how about the value of z??its unsigned but it doesnt show 132

Comment: The value of z that you're getting looks to be the maximum value of an unsigned 32-bit integer, minus the value of x.

Answer (score 1):

After first line x is 10000100 (132 is 10000100b) and it's the -124 value in machine (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Sign-and-magnitude_method)).
So after second line y is -124.
And after 3rd line z is 111...1110000100b. There are 1s on the higher bits because you're setting a negative number but when you print compiler prints it's binary value because z is unsigned.